# Google Sheets count how many cells contain a specific word / words?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to look at all cells in a set of columns/cells to count how many of them contain the word `WORDHERE` (in this example)

I've tried using:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A100, "WORDHERE"))
```

However this finds 0 as the cell contains other words/letters/numbers, if the cell only contains `WORDHERE` it works perfectly.

I've tried using several regeexxtract and regexmatch including the actual word as you can see below:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A100,REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A100, "WORDHERE")))
```

But again, it finds 0 matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not exactly answering what you are doing wrong, but here is what you can do:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100, "*WORDHERE*")
```

Comment: `SUM` isn't required, as `COUNTIF` returns a single value, which is the sum

Comment: Good call, @Ninjakannon , you're right. I'm not sure what I was thinking. Probably I was trying to do as little as possible to the formula in the question; or I was thinking about the more complicated formulas where one wants to sum countif times something. At this point it seems slimy to edit it, but I will leave this comment here so people know.

Comment: Okay, so I accepted a suggested edit from Wolf here to remove where I had unnecessarily said SUM. Of course now my answer is almost that of @JPV below, but it was a couple of days earlier. I'm leaving this comment here to make it clear I'm not tring to game the system.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need SUM around the COUNTIF.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100, "*WORDHERE*")
```

will work just as fine. The same can indeed be achieved with regexmatch in a more complicated formula:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(N(regexmatch(A7:A, "WORDHERE"))))
```

Here N-function is used to 'convert' the boolean values (TRUE or FALSE) to 1 or 0.

Comment: Or if you really, really want to use regexextract as in the question, =counta(arrayformula(ifError(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A100,"WORDHERE"))))